# ¿java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate... en android studio?

Tags: android-studio, imagen, glide

Estoy poniendo 3 Fragments con sus 3 xml correspondientes con un fondo que es una imagen pero no son muy grandes solo 3 MB,pero tienen una resolucion de 4K aproximadamente y me da el siguiente error

> 2019-07-29 22:36:11.418 21832-21832/com.example.imagenes E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.imagenes, PID: 21832
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.imagenes/com.example.imagenes.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
>        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
>        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.widget.RelativeLayout
>        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
>           at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:717)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:785)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
>           at com.example.imagenes.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
>        Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 697250412 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 377MB until OOM
>           at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
>           at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
>           at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:620)
>           at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:455)
>           at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1155)
>           at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:720)
>           at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:571)
>           at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:858)
>           at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:928)
>           at android.view.View.(View.java:4202)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:579)
>           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.(RelativeLayout.java:248)
>   2019-07-29 22:36:11.418 21832-21832/com.example.imagenes E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.(RelativeLayout.java:244)
>           at android.widget.RelativeLayout.(RelativeLayout.java:240)
>               ... 25 more

¿ Tengo que usar `Glide` ?

`Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(mBundle.getInt("Image")).into(mPlace);`

**¿Como lo usaria en un Fragment?**

Aqui está mi Fragment ( los otros 2 son igual) :

```
public class PageFragment1 extends Fragment {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.page_1, container,false);
    return rootView;


}
}
```

**y mi activity page_1.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/portada">
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/file_type_logo_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fontFamily="@font/simonetta_black_italic"
    android:text="Divertido"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="50sp" />
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/file_type_logo_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/downarrow" />
```

```
</RelativeLayout>
```

**portada es la imagen de 4K o no sé por qué se me crashea la app cuando la lanzo...**

**EDITO**

**MainActivity.java** :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private VerticalViewPager viewPager;
private PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.page_1);

    List<Fragment> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new PageFragment1());
    list.add(new PageFragment2());
    list.add(new PageFragment3());

    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pagerAdapter = new VPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),list);
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);



}



}
```

EDIT2:

Ahora no me deja iniciar la App, el error que tengo es el siguiente y no sé por qué :

> 2019-07-29 23:07:21.161 22572-22572/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
>   2019-07-29 23:07:21.281 22572-22572/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
>   2019-07-29 23:07:21.281 22572-22572/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
>   2019-07-29 23:07:23.305 22583-22583/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
>   2019-07-29 23:07:23.389 22583-22583/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
>   2019-07-29 23:07:23.389 22583-22583/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
>   2019-07-29 23:07:32.672 22596-22596/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
>   2019-07-29 23:07:32.719 22596-22596/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
>   2019-07-29 23:07:32.719 22596-22596/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
>   2019-07-29 23:07:36.569 22610-22610/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
>   2019-07-29 23:07:36.608 22610-22610/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
>   2019-07-29 23:07:36.608 22610-22610/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
>   2019-07-29 23:07:50.991 22622-22622/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
>   2019-07-29 23:07:51.030 22622-22622/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
>   2019-07-29 23:07:51.030 22622-22622/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
>   2019-07-29 23:07:51.259 22637-22637/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
>   2019-07-29 23:07:51.298 22637-22637/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
>   2019-07-29 23:07:51.298 22637-22637/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
>   2019-07-29 23:08:13.788 22651-22651/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
>   2019-07-29 23:08:13.837 22651-22651/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
>   2019-07-29 23:08:13.837 22651-22651/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
>   2019-07-29 23:08:31.742 22663-22663/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
>   2019-07-29 23:08:31.785 22663-22663/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
>   2019-07-29 23:08:31.785 22663-22663/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
>   2019-07-29 23:08:42.659 22687-22687/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
>   2019-07-29 23:08:42.680 22689-22689/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
>   2019-07-29 23:08:42.733 22687-22687/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
>   2019-07-29 23:08:42.733 22687-22687/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
>   2019-07-29 23:08:42.758 22689-22689/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
>   2019-07-29 23:08:42.758 22689-22689/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
>   2019-07-29 23:08:43.141 22711-22711/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
>   2019-07-29 23:08:43.186 22711-22711/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
>   2019-07-29 23:08:43.186 22711-22711/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
>   2019-07-29 23:08:44.223 22723-22723/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
>   2019-07-29 23:08:44.269 22723-22723/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
>   2019-07-29 23:08:44.270 22723-22723/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2

edit3:

07-30 00:00:00.720 30496-30496/? E/ImageLoader: /storage/emulated/0/.CacheOfEUI/com.letv.android.note/cache/journal.tmp: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/.CacheOfEUI/com.letv.android.note/cache/journal.tmp: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:87)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:72)
        at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.cache.disc.impl.ext.DiskLruCache.rebuildJournal(DiskLruCache.java:358)
        at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.cache.disc.impl.ext.DiskLruCache.open(DiskLruCache.java:250)
        at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.cache.disc.impl.ext.LruDiskCache.initCache(LruDiskCache.java:112)
        at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.cache.disc.impl.ext.LruDiskCache.(LruDiskCache.java:106)
        at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.cache.disc.impl.ext.LruDiskCache.(LruDiskCache.java:69)
        at com.letv.android.note.NoteApplication.initImageLoader(NoteApplication.java:129)
        at com.letv.android.note.NoteApplication.onCreate(NoteApplication.java:116)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1014)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4864)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1452)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5574)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
        at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:87) 
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:72) 
        at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.cache.disc.impl.ext.DiskLruCache.rebuildJournal(DiskLruCache.java:358) 
        at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.cache.disc.impl.ext.DiskLruCache.open(DiskLruCache.java:250) 
        at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.cache.disc.impl.ext.LruDiskCache.initCache(LruDiskCache.java:112) 
        at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.cache.disc.impl.ext.LruDiskCache.(LruDiskCache.java:106) 
        at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.cache.disc.impl.ext.LruDiskCache.(LruDiskCache.java:69) 
        at com.letv.android.note.NoteApplication.initImageLoader(NoteApplication.java:129) 
        at com.letv.android.note.NoteApplication.onCreate(NoteApplication.java:116) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1014) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4864) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1452) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5574) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Comment: Ok Rafa, veo tu pregunta pero indica como cargas las imágenes en el ImageView.

Comment: Hola @Jorgesys, verás, las imágenes las cargo tal como ves, de fondo , es decir , arriba en el xml en ``android:background="@drawable/portada"``

Comment: Para ponerte en situación, la App carga primero ``MainActivity.java`` y dentro de este, como ves, están los 3 Fragments.

Comment: @Rafa, recuerda que es super importante optimizar tus imágenes que uses como recursos en tu proyecto, no es necesario cargar todas con Picasso o Glide.  Cargas una imagen de 4k pero recuerda que al usar un ViewPager generalmente se crean las 3 vistas al mismo tiempo , la que ves en pantalla y las de los extremos, probablemente ahí estas cargando otras imagenes.

Comment: Te refieres que le baje el peso de las imagenes ?

Comment: Voy a probar y te digo..

Comment: @Jorgesys Estoy actualizando android studio que no me dejaba hacer nada, he bajado cada foto a 1.3 MB aprox, crees que con las 3 imagenes así, dejará? Cómo si no le puedo meter un ``Glide`` en ``Fragment`` en este caso , por si tampoco me deja ni reduciendo el tamaño...

Comment: Ahora no me deja iniciar al app, ni se lanza... he puesto edicion a ver que ves..

Comment: se me crashea la app al lanzarla, sabes que puede ser, @Jorgesys? puedes entrar con pantalla compartida en mi ordenador y ver que sucede? llevo horas y horas y estoy desesperadisimo.

Comment: 1.3MB puede ser menos ligero, revisa en el LogCat si encuentras donde diga "Caused by"

Comment: No, solo indica lo que he puesto arriba editado

Comment: Estoy impotente, ahora no va nada ni deja iniciar no entiendo, vamos al chat?

Comment: en el edit3 de arriba tienes tu ``caused by`` @Jorgesys

Comment: Y si, hay algunos archivos raros como fileoutputstream e intrumentation.java que tienen cosas en rojo...

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96775/discussion-between-jorgesys-and-rf-mvs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitivamente es un problema de consumo de memoria de hecho al iniciar tu aplicación indica que no puede inflar `page_1.xml` que es cargado por tu `Activity` principal.

Además como te comentaba estas usando un pager donde se cargan regularmente 3 fragmentos, el que es visible en pantalla y los que se encuentran a los extremos, si las imágenes no son optimizadas, tendrás el mismo problema.

---

Para solucionar este problema considera:

• Mueve las imagenes de alta resolución de /drawable a /drawable-xxhdpi o a /drawable-xxxhdpi
Esto provoca que el sistema operativo escale la imagen a una proporcion menor a partir de una densidad alta. Si se agregan las imagenes en /drawable y estas son de alta resolución, se tratara de cargar un bitmap con estas caracteristicas.

• En tu `MainActivity` no tienes que cargar el layout que cargara uno de los Fragmentos, aquí debes definir únicamente la clase pager (`VerticalViewPager`) al cual se le agregaran los `Fragments`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.example.imagenes.VerticalViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </com.example.imagenes.VerticalViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>
```

• Te sugiero también usar `Glide` para cargar las imágenes como fondo de los layouts

#### Establecer imagen de fondo en diseño relativo usando `Glide` en Android

Define un id a tu Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">
  ...
  ...
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Este sería un ejemplo cargando la imagen mediante Glide en un Fragment:

```
public class PageFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.page_1, container,false);

        /*----------------------------------------------*/
        //Carga imagen en RelativeLayout
        Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.portada).into(new CustomTarget<Drawable>() {
            @Override
            public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Drawable resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Drawable> transition) {
                rootView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout).setBackground(resource);
            }
            @Override
            public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) {
            }
        });
        /*----------------------------------------------*/

        return rootView;
        
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]